# How to match beginning of string "like" it were in character class?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a string in a file say:

```
abc
```

or

```
def abc
```

I want to match `abc` such that it can either appear at the beginning of the line or after a blank.

I can do it with matching multiple patterns, separating with `|` like:

```
/^abc|[[:blank:]]+abc/
```

But is there some way to include `^` i.e. **beginning of the string**  something like character class.

`^` at the beginning of character class would mean **negation** and other positions would mean just match the **caret ('^') character**.

Also, in my original case, the string is not just `abc`, instead it is a string matched with a a complex regex, so I prefer it to be as clean as possible. I am matching this regex inside an `awk` script. Although I still include `bash` tag because `system()` function can still be used within it. Speed doesn't matter much to me in my case, but clarity does.

Comment: In POSIX regexp terminology a **character class** is a pre-defined string that represents a set of characters, e.g. `[:space:]` or `[:alnum:]`. You can use those inside **bracket expressions** to match sets of characters in regexps, e.g. `[[:space:]]` or `[[:alnum:]]` or `[[:space:][:alnum:]]`. So what you're really asking isn't `is there some way to include ^ i.e. beginning of the line in character class.` as it's impossible to add a character to a character class, what you're asking is `is there some way to include ^ i.e. beginning of the line in a bracket expression.`

Comment: The answer to that is "no" because `^` in this context isn't a character, it's a regexp construct that represents "start of string" (not "start of line" - it only co-incidentally means "start of line" when the string you're working on is a line), so you can't include it in a bracket expression which is a set of characters plus negation `^` and range `-` of said characters.

Comment: @EdMorton yes i figured that out lately. Have also made corrections to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capturing group:

```
(^|[[:blank:]]+)abc
```

It will match the beginning of the string or a run of blanks. You can drop `+` if you don't need all blanks preceding `abc` in your match but the last.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
/(^|[[:blank:]])abc/
```

Start with `^` start or `[[:blank:]]`, then `abc`

Answer (score 2):

Beginning or line `^` is **not** a character, it's an anchor so it makes no sense to put it in a **character** class as well as `\A`, `$`, `\z` or `\b`.

In your case, you just need to test for wordboundary, there're no needs to use a capture group that slow down the regex:

```
\<abc
```

This is matching `abc` when preceeded by beginning of line or a non-word character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VOf8e1/1)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Although this doesn't work for me. As mentioned in the question, I am using it within `awk`. `awk '/\babc/' file` or even latest version of `gawk` doesn't produce anything. Upvoted because its otherwise correct.

Comment: @Mihir: Sorry, wordboundary (gawk) is `\<`, see my edit

Comment: That'd match `abc` after punctuation, etc. too though, e.g. `whatever.abc`.

Comment: @EdMorton: True, that's what I said with "when preceeded by a non-word character". My answer was more about why we can't put a carret in a character class.